# Regex expression to replace a string containing a substring with the substring only in a DataFrame

Tags: python, regex, dataframe, replace

I am trying to replace all strings within a Python dataframe column that contain a certain substring, with only the substring itself. Preferably it would be an 'inplace=True' sort of result.

I've tried various regex expressions, unfortunately as I'm new to this, everything I have tried has not yielded the desired result. I am on Python 3.7.3.

I think the code I need to conduct the replacement within the dataframe is

df.replace(to_replace = *regex expression that identifies substring in string containing the substring* , value = 'substring', regex = True). So below is an example of what I'm trying to do

```py
#original dataframe
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'brand':['brand1 & brand2','brand1/brand3','brand4 brand3','brand1 and brand 6']})
df

    brand
0   brand1 & brand2
1   brand6
2   brand1/brand3
3   brand9
4   brand4 brand3
5   brand8
6   brand1 and brand6

#desired result

df

    brand
0   brand1
1   brand6
2   brand1
3   brand9
4   brand4 brand3
5   brand8
6   brand1
```

So far, my regex expressions have effected no change. Just as a note, the brand names don't actually include 1-9, to avoid any possible confusion. The actual df I'm manipulating has a little over 10k rows, but within the column 'brands' strings that contain brand1 comprise about 2k of the 10k, and I need to replace all of the strings containing brand1 with just 'brand1' alone.

Comment: did you add the inplace=True

Comment: the data you put with `pd.DataFrame({'brand':['brand1 & brand2','brand1/brand3','brand4 brand3','brand1 and brand 6']})` and the data you have shown as input don't match. Also is it now clear what you are trying to replace with what.

Comment: it should match now. In terms of what I'm trying to replace, the example shows that any rows containing brand1, I want to replace those strings with just brand 1 alone. so row 0 originally is literally the string 'brand1 & brand2' and I want to replace it with just 'brand1'. And so on for the other rows.

Comment: So, what is going on with row 4? why don't it just become brand4?

Comment: I need to leave that row as is. Basically, all rows that don't have brand1 somewhere in the string, need to be left alone. Only rows with brand1 would be processed with the regex.

Comment: Try `df['brand'] = df['brand'].str.replace(r'.*\b(brand1)\b.*', r'\1')`. It should avoid changing the values to `brand1` in case there are longer words like `cbrand1` or `brand11`. If you need a case insensitive replace use `r'(?i).*\b(brand1)\b.*'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
df['brand'] = np.where(df['brand'].str.contains('brand1'), 'brand1',df['brand'])
```

**Input**

```
    brand
0   brand1 & brand2
1   brand6
2   brand1/brand3
3   brand9
4   brand4 brand3
5   brand1 and brand 6
```

**Output**

```
    brand
0   brand1
1   brand6
2   brand1
3   brand9
4   brand4 brand3
5   brand1
```

Comment: That did it. Thanks. I'll accept when it lets me. I'm a bit surprised I didn't need regex...I'll have to read up on np.where. Thank you.

Comment: Glad to help. It is always better to show input & expected output & explain what you are trying to achieve. This helps others to suggest various ways of achieving it & some of those methods may be more efficient than the one we have in mind :-)

Comment: Could you explain some more about how this works? What's special in particular about `brand1` in the code, seeing as the output produces other brand<num> values?

Comment: There is nothing special with `brand1`. In `np.where`, you can do something when the condition is true & when the condition is false. what i have done is told that when the string contains `brand1` , make the value of the cell as `brand1`, else keep the content as in column `brand`

Comment: If the solution helped you, consider upvoting/accepting the answer.